# Additional information: Failed to establish a connection to 'Server'

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to create a Service to update a postgresql database using topshelf, npgsql and C# but I get the following error when trying to connect to the database.

A first chance exception of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' occurred in Npgsql.dll

An exception of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' occurred in Npgsql.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Failed to establish a connection to 'HostName'

This is my connection string.

```
conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=HostName;Port=5432;User Id=UID;Password=pass;
                             Database=dbname;");
```

I use the the same connection line for an asp.net C# webapp which is working fine. My pg_hba.conf file has the line host all all `0.0.0.0/0` `md5` and `postgresql.conf` file has the line `listen_addresses = '*'`. I am also able to connect to the database through pgAdmin with the same log in credentials. I have also added a rule to the firewall on my computer for port 5432 and the host server does not have the firewall enabled.

I then tried to run the same code on the same system the postgresql server is hosted using localhost as the server and received the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using the NpsqlConnectionStringBuilder and adding the properties manually, it may be something daft in the NpsqlConnection constructor?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace for the error, if you have one.

Comment: I updated the post with the rest of the error, which doesn't add much information, but i'm unsure how to get a stack trace.